# Django cx_Oracle connection.cursor().description for oracle cursor datatype

Tags: django, oracle, django-views, cx-oracle

is it possible to get description for cursor datatype inside the Django view? 
The thing is when I execute a raw SQL i can get description by calling `cursor().description` but when i perform  `cursor().callfunc('oracleTestFunc',cx_Oracle.CURSOR,)`
(oracleTestFunc returns cursor)
I cannot get fields description. So the problem is to gain the `description`. How can I implement that?

UPDATE 

My oracle function is

```
create or replace package body test_cl is

function ret_proc_run return sys_refcursor is
  retval sys_refcursor;
begin

open retval for 
  select id_proc,inst_id,run_now from proc_run;

 return retval;
end;

end test_cl;
```

In Django view i call it this way

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
results=cursor.callfunc('test_cl.ret_proc_run',cx_Oracle.CURSOR,)
```

So what i want to do is to get access to the individual fields returned by oracle function (those are `id_proc`,`inst_id`,`run_now`) later to use in template.
I thought it would be possible by `cursor.description` method but after further reading of documentation i found out that it is not possible in that way because it will return `none` for cursor datatypes.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the description from the cursor that is returned from the function?

Comment: I want to call description function on a cursor. when i cal it i get none in case of cursor, but when i perform a raw sql query in a view i can call the description method on it.

Comment: Django wraps things a bit. You may want to try with cx_Oracle directly to see if what you want to do works fine outside of Django. You can get the raw cx_Oracle connection from within Django. I can track down the code if you need that. Let me know.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga The source for this question is that i want to ger cursor from oracle to django and get access to individual fileds of cursor within the view.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I'm not sure what you are trying to say. Trying to do what you want to do *outside* Django first is a good idea -- that will eliminate any issues you are having with the Django framework which does wrap things a bit (which is normally a convenience). If that isn't an option for you, please explain your situation a bit more in your question! Thanks.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga Please see the update of the question.

Comment: Did my updated answer help?

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga See the comment on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, cursor.description is the right attribute to examine, but from your question description you are looking at the wrong cursor! You need to use the cursor that was returned from the function (in your case named "results"). The other cursor (the one that called the stored procedure) will return None as expected since you didn't execute a query.

If you do need to get at a raw cx_Oracle cursor (unwrapped by Django) you can do the following:

```
from django.db import connection
connection.cursor()
rawCursor = connection.connection.cursor()
```

The second line ensures that a connection has indeed been established. The final line gets the raw connection and creates a cursor using it.

Comment: Your hint that i should not call ``description`` on ``cursor`` was very helpful. I just added a ``res=results.fetchall()`` and then i managed to access ``res.description``. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you mark this as the correct answer, then?